# Is there a golangci-lint rule that checks for local variables only on specific functions?

Tags: go, scope, local-variables, golangci-lint

I am aware of shadowing checks from govet but I am looking for something more specific.
I am looking for a golangci-lint plugin that allows us to force local variables on specific functions.
Ideally, something like this would fail my linter check:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

var myglobalvar = "hello from global"

func testme(i string, j bool) {
        fmt.Println(i)
}

func main() {
    fmt.Printf("Hello, Golang\n")
        mylocalvar := "hello from local"
        testme(mylocalvar)        // linter passes here
        testme(myglobalvar)       // linter fails here
}
```

I have searched over on https://golangci-lint.run/usage/linters/ but only shadowing seems close. It's possible that I do not know the language/keywords around this interaction.